# End of chirp in phase 0

Tags: python, chirp, sweep

I would like the chirp to end in phase zero.
Chirp time or end frequency may vary slightly.

Now I'm checking the maplot output.
I observe the same thing at the output of the sound card.

In this solution, the chirp does not always end in phase zero.

help find a solution.

Thanks for the help.
Andrew

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp

f0 = 7000
f1 = 17000
samplerate = 192000
T = 0.0013
T = np.ceil(T*f1)/f1 # new T
t = np.arange(0, int(T*samplerate)) / samplerate
w = chirp(t, f0=f0, f1=f1, t1=T,phi=270, method='linear')
   
fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(6,1))
ax.set_title("Chirp ")
ax.plot(w) 
show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivations [here](https://overlordgolddragon.github.io/test-signals/#signal-general-forms-derivations) - you can pick any `tmin`, `tmax`, and `fmin`, `fmax` for some number of samples or sampling rate `N`.

We adjust the code one line toward the end to rescale `phi` to end as an integer multiple of $2\pi$ to yield zero phase; this has the effect of nudging `fmin` and `fmax`, slightly or greatly depending on all other parameters - see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5y1qlf8kmd).

An alternative variant that forces only the *end* of the chirp to be zero phase will exactly preserve `fmin` and `fmax`, by subtracting. Forcing all, zero phase at `tmin` and `tmax` without changing `fmin` and `fmax` is impossible.

Taking your parameters, with cosine and sine:

[image]

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _lchirp(N, tmin=0, tmax=1, fmin=0, fmax=None):
    fmax = fmax if fmax is not None else N / 2
    t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, N, endpoint=True)

    a = (fmin - fmax) / (tmin - tmax)
    b = (fmin*tmax - fmax*tmin) / (tmax - tmin)

    phi = (a/2)*(t**2 - tmin**2) + b*(t - tmin)
    phi *= (2*np.pi)
    return phi

def lchirp(N, tmin=0, tmax=1, fmin=0, fmax=None, zero_phase_tmin=True, cos=True):
    phi = _lchirp(N, tmin, tmax, fmin, fmax)
    if zero_phase_tmin:
        phi *= ( (phi[-1] - phi[-1] % (2*np.pi)) / phi[-1] )
    else:
        phi -= (phi[-1] % (2*np.pi))
    fn = np.cos if cos else np.sin
    return fn(phi)

#%%######################################################################
f0 = 7000
f1 = 17000
samplerate = 192000
T = .0013

N = int(samplerate * T)
tmin = 0
tmax = T

t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, N, endpoint=True)
for zero_phase_min in (True, False):
    for cos in (True, False):
        x = lchirp(N=int(samplerate * T), tmin=tmin, tmax=tmax, fmin=f0, fmax=f1,
                   zero_phase_tmin=zero_phase_min, cos=cos)
        plt.plot(t, x)
        plt.title("cos={}, zero_phase_tmin={}".format(cos, zero_phase_min),
                  weight='bold', fontsize=17, loc='left')
        plt.show()
```

Comment: many thanks.  Andrew.

Comment: added changes to my project.  https://github.com/karu2003/sweep_gen

Answer (score 0):

For a linear chirp you can do this by slightly "nudging" the upper frequency. I don't think the build in Python function supports so yo have to do this yourself manually.

Let's assume we have a chirp with N samples and the normalized start and end frequencies $\omega_0$ and $\omega_0$

The frequency as a function of time is then

$$\omega[n] = \omega_0 + (\omega_1-\omega_0)\frac{n}{N}$$

To get the phase we need to integrate

$$\phi[n] = \sum_{k=0}^n\omega[k] = \omega_0\cdot n + (\omega_1-\omega_0)\frac{n^2}{2N}$$

In order to have a seamless chirp you want the phase at $n=N$ to be an integer multiple of $2\pi$. We get

$$\phi[N] = \frac{N}{2}(\omega_1+\omega_0)$$

So you need to find the nearest integer multiple of $2\pi$ and then recalculate the upper frequency again.

$$\phi_{clean} = 2\pi\cdot round(\frac{\phi[N]}{2\pi})$$

$$\omega_{clean} = \frac{2 \phi_{clean}}{N}-\omega_0$$

and your sweep becomes finally

$$x[n] = sin \left ( \omega_0\cdot n + (\omega_{clean}-\omega_0)\frac{n^2}{2N} \right) $$

Comment: Presumably the samples in the _periodic_ chirp of period $N$ are numbered from $0$ to $N-1$? So that the phase is $0$ at $n=0$ and again at $n=N$ and so the next period of the periodic chirp starts again at $n=N$ with frequency $\omega_0$?

Comment: Yes that's generally the assumption

Comment: Thank you,

i changed the code.
the result is very bad.
the new frequency and phase have not changed.  

https://github.com/karu2003/chirp_phase_zero

:( :(